# How to align Column Header Text in to left Datagridview Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

[image][![enter

How to align header text in left, any one help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try playing with the padding of the header and the rows:

```
this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0);
this.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(5);
```

Comment: i have already tried this. but it doesn't work for me. i want to align the cell values and header text in left side as i showed in image

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood you problem. I eddited my Answer.